# Incorrect syntax near '=' in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query below is giving the error: `Incorrect syntax near '='`.

```
"UPDATE EF_MOCCU_MAP_MAIN"+
" SET CAST(MONETARY_CLAIM AS NVARCHAR(1))= ? ," +  
" DATA_INPUT_SELECT=?"+
" WHERE COURT_UNIT_ID=? AND MOC_CODE=?";
```

Initially I had the error:

`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Y' to data type int`

Then I cast the SQL like `"SET CAST(MONETARY_CLAIM AS NVARCHAR(1))= ? "` and after that I receive the incorrect syntax error.

Comment: This part looks wrong: `SET CAST(MONETARY_CLAIM AS NVARCHAR(1))= ?` - should it be `SET MONETARY_CLAIM=?` ??

Comment: I think you cannot cast  the left side of the set, you have too cast the right side.

Comment: It may be helpful to tell us which database type you are using.

Comment: Show us how do you set the first parameter

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the error message

Comment: as i mention i do cast because .. it have an Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Y' to data type int error ... so that's why is do in this way

Comment: What value are you trying to set `MONETARY_CLAIM` to and what datatype is it? Maybe `BIT` and you're trying to set it to 'Y' instead of 1?

Answer (score 1):

As others noted this is wrong.

`SET CAST(MONETARY_CLAIM AS NVARCHAR(1)) = <something>`

You can set a value into a column, you cannot set a value into any expression.
It just doesn't make sense (as in most programming languages).

Comment: as i mention 
i do cast because .. it have an Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Y' to data type int error ... so that's why is do in this way ...

Comment: @pink As mentioned, this cannot be done. You'll have to cast the param `?` then

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SET MONETARY_CLAIM = CASE WHEN ISNULL(?,'N') = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If you are collecting a parameter/value 'Y', but sending it into a BIT or INT field [MONETARY_CLAIM] you must change the data type of the parameter to suit the field. I suggest you try using a case expression.